# How to get the value i required from a single line

Tags: linux, shell-script

the line is like shown below in a file
how to get the value I required

```
nam=1554354154(pe85461)
```

i)how to load the value inside the brackets to a variable.

ii)how to load the value of the nam to a variable.

Comment: is this the only line available in that file?

Comment: yes, it was the only line

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NaME=$(awk -F '=' '{print $1}' test.txt)
VaLUE=$(awk -F '[()]' '{print $(NF-1)}' test.txt)
```